# AttributeError: module 'numbers' has no attribute 'Integral'

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

Im working on a Mac.
Python 3.7.0 is installed. Installed Anaconda, Pandas and Numpy.

In the command line if I type in Python and inside the Python shell I can type in import Pandas and it looks like it worked.

But in Komodo Editor if I execute:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import pandas
```

I get the following error:

```
AttributeError: module 'numbers' has no attribute 'Integral'
```

EDIT:

Here is the full Code:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import pandas

def main():
    print('Hello, World.')

if __name__ == '__main__': main()
```

Here is the Traceback:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/Barry/Documents/Python/testpanda.py", line 3, in <module>
    import pandas
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/__init__.py", line 13, in <module>
    __import__(dependency)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/numpy/__init__.py", line 142, in <module>
    from . import add_newdocs
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/numpy/add_newdocs.py", line 13, in <module>
    from numpy.lib import add_newdoc
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/numpy/lib/__init__.py", line 8, in <module>
    from .type_check import *
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/numpy/lib/type_check.py", line 11, in <module>
    import numpy.core.numeric as _nx
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/numpy/core/__init__.py", line 35, in <module>
    from . import _internal  # for freeze programs
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/numpy/core/_internal.py", line 18, in <module>
    from .numerictypes import object_
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/numpy/core/numerictypes.py", line 948, in <module>
    _register_types()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/numpy/core/numerictypes.py", line 943, in _register_types
    numbers.Integral.register(integer)
AttributeError: module 'numbers' has no attribute 'Integral'
```

Comment: please post your full code as well as full traceback you get, not just the last line

Comment: https://github.com/numpy/numpy/issues/9872#issuecomment-337098073

Comment: @buran, I just edited it. I added the full code and Traceback.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Looking at the [`github link`](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/issues/9872#issuecomment-337098073) shared by `Dušan Maďar`, **it is most likely that you have a file called '`numbers.py`' which might be interfering with the python `Lib`.**

**Renaming that file should fix the issue.**

Comment: Sadly not. My file is called "testpanda.py" and not numbers.py.

Comment: This is weird as hell. I have indeed a file called "numbers.py" inside the same folder where my "testpandas.py" is. numbers.py wasn't even open at all its just enough to be in the same folder and it will mess with it. wtf

Comment: @Barry, it may be other file named numbers.py that is located in the same folder as your testpanda.py, see https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/modules.html#the-module-search-path to get better understanding of module search path order

Comment: @Buran, that's crazy. Yes that was the problem. It confused me because this file is named "testpanda.py". What a weird bug. Hope they fix that.

Comment: @Barry, that's not a bug. Check the link I added in my previous comment

Comment: Yeah I did. I just don't think thats acceptable. Im sure they could work it out so it won't happen if you happen to have a file named "Numbers.py". Its not very uncommon to use such name considering you are dealing with numbers and you are using python. This error and me asking on Stackoverflow could be easily avoided and 45 people who read this threat could all save their time too. If you add up all the minutes that I and other spend their time on figuring this out and use that time for work or research.

Comment: @ParvBanks, Thanks! Same thing was happening to me when doing 'Import numpy' I renamed my file from numbers.py to num_int_float_str.py and everything works.

Answer (score 1):

To anyone out there who stumbles across this!! I had this same issue - had just downloaded Anaconda3 with Python, was setting up a new Jupyter Notebook. When you do this, it automatically imports a bunch of the libraries that are saved as part of anaconda3. My Kernel kept disconnecting (and I was unable to create a notebook) with the following error:

```
    AttributeError: module 'numbers' has no attribute 'Integral'
```

As it turns out, all the Python library files are super basic names, "copy.py," "decimal.py," numbers.py." Well I had previously been working on a Python class prior to this and had written short piece of code named "numbers." This was conflicting with the "numbers" python file in my library, and while they were saved in different locations, Jupyter, and consequently Python, was importing the wrong "numbers.py" and that was causing the error. From what I can tell, if you have ANY python files accidentally named the same as one in the Anaconda Library, you need to find them and RENAME them to something else. I did just that and it appears to be the fix. I can now create Jupyter notebooks with no issues.