# AttributeError: module 'numbers' has no attribute 'Integral' in scripy

Tags: python, attributeerror

Python newbie here coming up with Error below while trying to import scripy using Idle on Python 3.82

This is the whole code error which comes up when running it.

```
from scipy.linalg import inv as my_inv

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#11>", line 1, in <module>
    from scipy.linalg import inv as my_inv
  File "C:\Users\alank\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\scipy\__init__.py", line 63, in <module>
    from numpy import show_config as show_numpy_config
  File "C:\Users\alank\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\numpy\__init__.py", line 142, in <module>
    from . import core
  File "C:\Users\alank\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\numpy\core\__init__.py", line 72, in <module>
    from . import numerictypes as nt
  File "C:\Users\alank\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\numpy\core\numerictypes.py", line 599, in <module>
    _register_types()
  File "C:\Users\alank\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\numpy\core\numerictypes.py", line 594, in _register_types
    numbers.Integral.register(integer)
AttributeError: module 'numbers' has no attribute 'Integral'
>>> AttributeError: module 'numbers' has no attribute 'Integral'
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
>>> from scipy.linalg import inv as my_inv
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#13>", line 1, in <module>
    from scipy.linalg import inv as my_inv
  File "C:\Users\alank\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\scipy\__init__.py", line 63, in <module>
    from numpy import show_config as show_numpy_config
  File "C:\Users\alank\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\numpy\__init__.py", line 142, in <module>
    from . import core
  File "C:\Users\alank\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\numpy\core\__init__.py", line 72, in <module>
    from . import numerictypes as nt
  File "C:\Users\alank\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\numpy\core\numerictypes.py", line 599, in <module>
    _register_types()
  File "C:\Users\alank\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\numpy\core\numerictypes.py", line 594, in _register_types
    numbers.Integral.register(integer)
AttributeError: module 'numbers' has no attribute 'Integral'
>>> from scipy.linalg import inv as my_inv
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#14>", line 1, in <module>
    from scipy.linalg import inv as my_inv
  File "C:\Users\alank\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\scipy\__init__.py", line 63, in <module>
    from numpy import show_config as show_numpy_config
  File "C:\Users\alank\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\numpy\__init__.py", line 142, in <module>
    from . import core
  File "C:\Users\alank\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\numpy\core\__init__.py", line 72, in <module>
    from . import numerictypes as nt
  File "C:\Users\alank\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\numpy\core\numerictypes.py", line 599, in <module>
    _register_types()
  File "C:\Users\alank\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\numpy\core\numerictypes.py", line 594, in _register_types
    numbers.Integral.register(integer)
AttributeError: module 'numbers' has no attribute 'Integral'
```

Comment: What are the scipy and numpy versions. You can check with `pip show <package name>

Comment: Are you sure you don't have a file named `numbers.py` next to your script: https://stackoverflow.com/a/53669402/9392216

Comment: Hi Thanks, it turned out had a numbers,py which did not realise, but thanks for all help