# results to be written in excel column B

Tags: python, xlrd, goslate

The below code currently translate each words from the Excel sheet for the words location in Column A, But the results it currently gives me in the editor but I want the translated output/result in the same excel sheet in Column B. The below code gives me an error.
please help me with the code for the results to be written in excel in column B.

```
import xlrd
import goslate

loc = r"C:\path\fruits.xlsx"
gs = goslate.Goslate()

wb = xlrd.open_workbook(loc) 
sheet = wb.sheet_by_index(0)
  
for i in range(sheet.nrows): 
    print(gs.translate(sheet.cell_value(i, 0), 'de'))
    print(sheet.cell_value(i, 1)
```

I am receiving the below error

```
 return self._cell_values[rowx][colx]
IndexError: list index out of range
```

Please someone help me to write my output/result in the same excel in Column B

Answer (score 0):

The error is caused because you don't have a `B` is empty and package does not read the column from sheet.

To write the translated result to the sheet, you can do something like this:

I don't think `xlrd` can write to sheet. You will need to use `xlwt` package. You will need to install it `pip install xlwt`

```py
import xlrd
import xlwt # this package is going to write to sheet
import goslate
loc = "dummy.xlsx"
translated = "dummy2.xlsx" # location to where store the modified sheet

gs = goslate.Goslate()

# crate a workbook using xlwt package in order to write to it.
wbt = xlwt.Workbook() # there is a typo here. this should be wbt
ws = wbt.add_sheet('A Test Sheet') # change this to your sheet name

rwb = xlrd.open_workbook(loc) 
sheet = wb.sheet_by_index(0)
  
for i in range(sheet.nrows): 
    ws.write(i, 0, sheet.cell_value(i, 0)) # this will write the A column value
    ws.write(i, 1, gs.translate(sheet.cell_value(i, 0), 'de')) # this will write the B column value

wbt.save(translated) # this will save the sheet.
```

As for making changes in the same file, I my opinion you should not do that. The file is already opend by another process in read mode. Changing it can result in unexpected behavior. But if you intent to do that, backup your file, and set the loc for both when reading and when saving file.

Comment: When i run this code, i am getting the below error  `from _decimal import *
AttributeError: module 'numbers' has no attribute 'Number'`

Comment: Check this answer out https://stackoverflow.com/a/53669402/8711654

Comment: I followed this link after i followed, when i run this code receiving this error `NameError: name 'wbt' is not defined`

Comment: Fixed a typo in answer.

Comment: Not working like how? What is the error you are getting?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/222576/discussion-between-faizan-and-shan).

Answer (score 0):

You're getting the error because xlrd addresses columns are zero based and per documentation the xlrd ignores cells with no data.

so you could access column A by doing

```
sheet.cell_value(i, 0)
```

and write to column B by doing

```
sheet._cell_types[i][1] = xlrd.XL_CELL_TEXT
sheet._cell_values[i][1] = source
```

however `xlrd` is only for reading, so you'd have to use `xlwt` to save any changes.

Saving changes brings up another issue, you're source file is ".xlsx" extension, while `xlrd` does read this format, `xlwt` only writes to the older ".xls" format.

To read and write to ".xlsx" format with one library you can use `openpyxl`, using this library your code would look like this:

```
import openpyxl
import goslate

loc = r"C:\path\fruits.xlsx"
gs = goslate.Goslate()

wb = openpyxl.load_workbook(loc)
sheet = wb.active

for i in range(2, sheet.max_row + 1):
    original = sheet.cell(row=i, column=1).value
    translated = gs.translate(original, 'de')
    sheet.cell(row=i, column=2).value = translated
    
wb.save(loc)
```

Comment: This code is not working gives me below error `Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\Users\userid\translation.py", line 14, in <module>
    translated = gs.translate(source, 'de')
NameError: name 'source' is not defined`

Comment: on that line `source` should have been `original`, I fixed the code in answer.