# using numpy in python

Tags: python, numpy

When I try to use numpy, I get an error, which is below. I have 2 questions, how do I work with numpy, I used pip to install, and how do I understand the error messages. I am a newbie in python

```
import numpy as np


array_a = np.array([1, 2, 3, 4, 5])
print(array_a)
```

Error:

```
[Johnnys-MBP:~/Desktop/python] johnbarrett% /usr/local/bin/python3 /Users/johnbarrett/Desktop/python/data.py
<class 'complex'>
1.4
2
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/johnbarrett/Desktop/python/data.py", line 1, in <module>
    import numpy as np
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/numpy/__init__.py", line 140, in <module>
    from . import core
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/numpy/core/__init__.py", line 70, in <module>
    from . import numerictypes as nt
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/numpy/core/numerictypes.py", line 566, in <module>
    _register_types()
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/numpy/core/numerictypes.py", line 561, in _register_types
    numbers.Integral.register(integer)
AttributeError: module 'numbers' has no attribute 'Integral'
```

Comment: Looks like this was answered already [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53668779/attributeerror-module-numbers-has-no-attribute-integral).

Answer (score 0):

Do you have the NumPy module installed on your computer? You have to locate it online and install it.
https://scipy.org/install.html
I found a package of a bunch of different scientific modules in python and within that (after I installed it it was about 700mbs) was a number of python terminals and numpy was installed on them. I did not get it to work on my standard 3.7/3.8 IDE offical python distributions. Sorry if this doesn't help, hope it does!

*edit* I choose WinPy BTW I have an intel chipset too and have no issues

Comment: thanks so much for your comment. I installed numpy with pip3, and it's installed. I installed conda and now everything is working. very strange!

Answer (score 0):

You can install any IDE like pycharm. It will be more convenient to work with python. If you already have pycharm, then you can install numpy in this way: file-> settings-> python interpreter-> '+' symbol on the top right of the screen-> now u can install any packages using the search box. Hope you will find this helpful :)

Comment: I use Visual Code, the strange thing it works with conda, but not with the python installation. I have numpy installed,m it makes no sense to me. thanks so much for your comment