# When I try to run this code I get AttributeError and I get the same error with pandas and numpy

Tags: pandas, numpy

[numpy and pandas don't work. How can I solve this problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Sv7ke.png)

Comment: If you have a user-defined module named 'numbers.py'. Change its name to something else.

Answer (score 1):

You have a `numbers.py` file that creates conflict.
Renamining it should fix the issue.

The full answer can be found here : https://stackoverflow.com/a/53669402/15179457.

In general, you can search the error message you face, someone may have faced it before. :)