# How can I fix this, AttributeError: module "numbers" has no attribute 'Integral'

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am getting the following error when I try to run this python file.

How can I fix this?

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

fileobj = open('marchweatherfull.csv', 'r')
data = fileobj.readlines()
fileobj.close()

mins = [] # do the same for maxs, nines and threes
maxs = []
nines = []
threes = []

for line in data:
    splitline = line.split(',')
    mins.append(float(splitline[2]))
    maxs.append(float(splitline[3]))
    nines.append(float(splitline[10]))
    threes.append(float(splitline[16]))

dates = [d for d in range(1,32)]
plt.plot(dates, mins, dates, maxs, dates, nines, dates, threes)
plt.show()


print(mins)
```

This is the error below:

[3, 6, 9, 12, 15]
Traceback (most recent call last) :
File "weather.py"
line 5, in

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
File
"/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/matplotlib/
init.py", line 139, in «modules
from
• import book, resetup
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/matplotlib/cbook/init.py",line32,in<modules
import numpy as np
File
"/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/numpy/init.py",line142,in<modules
from . import core
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/numpy/core/_*init*.py",line 72, in «module>
from . import numerictypes as nt
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/numpy/core/numerictypes.py",line 599, in «module>
register types()
File "/us/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/numpy/core/numerictypes.py",line 594, in
register _ty
DeS
numbers. Integral.register (integer)
AttributeError: module
"numbers" has no attribute 'Integral'

[Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/o1hY6.png)

Comment: You should paste the stacktrace here, instead of adding it as an image. Images don't work well for people using screen readers.

Comment: I've changed it, maybe now have a look.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In another stackoverflow similar Q says:

"Looking at the github link shared by Dušan Maďar, it is most likely that you have a file called 'numbers.py' which might be interfering with the python Lib.

Renaming that file should fix the issue."

[Link to Q](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53668779/attributeerror-module-numbers-has-no-attribute-integral)

Comment: Oh alright removing numbers.py fixed the error. Thanks very much for your help.

Answer (score 0):

i just copy and pasted to "numbers1.py", then use numbers1 to import Number package, it works on me

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).