# Numpy error (numpy not working) instead of adding numbers or running the code in the file its taking input [ Enter a number:-]

Tags: python, numpy

```
import numpy as np
x = np.array([[1,2],[3,4]])
y = np.array([[5,6],[7,8]])
print("Addition: ")
print(np.add(x,y))
print("Subtraction: ")
print(np.subtract(x,y))
print("Multiplication: ")
print(np.multiply(x,y))
print("Divison: ")
print(np.divide(x,y))
```

Output
Enter first number:-4
4.0  <class 'float'>
Enter second number:-64
(64+0j)  <class 'complex'>
Enter third number:-45
(45+0j)  <class 'complex'>

I have deleted the numpy and reinstall it,then also its not working
[Error image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5Gect.png) 
[Code file image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vcwjQ.png) 
[Correct output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LvevD.png)

Comment: Your code doesn't seem to match your output description.

Comment: Are you sure you are running the right python file, and that you don't have unsaved changed? There is no "Enter first number" in your code

Comment: Try to launch a script.py which contains only import numpy
print(numpy.__version__)

Comment: yes i am running the right file

Comment: did'nt understand
@Try to launch a script.py which contains only import numpy print(numpy.__version__)

Comment: And the code you posted above is the contents of that file? (`exp13Q10_1.py`)

Comment: yes its in that file
@Tyler V

Comment: I agree the output you show us is different from the code you gave us

Comment: @TylerV V
I have run it more than three times see the image 
code file image

Comment: Check the answer below - is there a "numbers.py" in that folder or somewhere on your python path? From the screenshot you added it looks like there is one - so try renaming that file.

Comment: @ Tyler V
 what to name that file ? or delete that file ??

Comment: You could either delete or rename it to pretty much anything else (e.g. `my_numbers.py`). Apparently numpy calls `import numbers` internally and it is pulling in your numbers.py file instead of the numpy one.

Comment: Thank @overmach for the answer below - that is a really non-intuitive behavior

Comment: ok but thank you very much both 
@ overmach ,  
Tyler V

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The output doesn't seem to match the code you posted, however, since the error is:

> AttributeError: module 'numbers' has no attribute 'Integral'

the problem could be that you have a file called *numbers.py* inside the same folder of *exp13Q10_1.py* or in the same search path as explained in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53668779/attributeerror-module-numbers-has-no-attribute-integral).

EDIT:
As explained [in "The Module Search Path" paragraph](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/modules.html#the-module-search-path) of Python documentation, when you import a module (let's call it *my_module*) the interpreter searches for a built-in module with that name, if it doesn't find it, it searches for `my_module.py` in a list of directories given by the variable `sys.path`.

`sys.path` is initialized from these locations:

- The directory containing the input script (or the current directory when no file is specified).
- `PYTHONPATH` (a list of directory names, with the same syntax as the shell variable PATH).
- The installation-dependent default (by convention including a site-packages directory, handled by the site module).

Take a look at the linked paragraph for more information of `sys.path` and `PYTHONPATH`.

Comment: Yes thanks ✌️@overmach i rename the file numbers.py in my python folder and then it worked